# ASP.NET 1.1: server hanging/not responding - how to debug this?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Ok, I know it should not be 1.1, but as the client is not paying the migration (and server-maintenace), it hasn't been done yet :(
(Win2003, IIS6, ASP1.1)

Until yesterday the app was not working and returned errors. But at least it returned **something**! So I did some debugging, added missing DLLs etc. - and suddenly I'm no longer getting anything back, the browser waits endlessly to close the request.

Application-logging did not return anything, it feels like the app isn't even coming to Page_Load. So I went to the IIS-Log - and the last entry was the request for the HTML-page which linked to the aspx-page.

Any ideas how I can diagnose that? I'm stumped :((

Comment: any code in global.asax? (Session_Start, Application_Start) that could cause the trouble?

Comment: no, I don't think so. My global.asax is a one-liner which links to the APL-workspace of the application:  <%@ Application Language="apl" Inherits="glob" src="ciwrefdb.dws"%>
And I've set tracing on the 1st cmd in Application_Start, but it never comes to that point :(

Comment: can you open a simple html page from your web server? If yes, then check whether your applicaition pool has the correct .net version

Comment: Yes, I can open the my personal start-page which has the links to ASP-apps. And I have ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0-apps which work, it's only the .aspx in that special directory which do not work. I have check that 1.1 is assigned to these.

Comment: No exceptions in EventLog on Server?

Comment: Nope :((

But actully I must correct myself: I found another 1.1-app which is not working (and it definitely did before), so it looks like a more general issue, so I will do a little maintenance now...